# Using multimap to match data from a stream

Tags: javascript, performance, stream

I am using a multimap to match requests with their pair as soon as I get them. Order matters because it's "first come first serve". However, I don't know if multimap is the optimal approach to this problem.

```js
// Multimap insertion:
function insert(map, key, value) {
  //:=> check positive dipole in Map.
  let values = map.get(key);
  //:=> If array results :=> push item into selected postive dipole array queue.
  if (values) values.push(value);
  // else dipole does not exist 
  //:=>hash dipole && set to current iteration
  else map.set(key, [value]);
}

// Multimap retrieval:
function retrieve(map, key) {
  let values = map.get(key);
  //:=> If values results from lookup 
  if (values) {
    //:=> remove last to list and first to matching object in array
    let value = values.pop();
    //if empty :=> remove negative identifying dipole hash
    if (values.length === 0) map.delete(key);
    //:=> return last matching object from array
    return value;
  }
}

// Match items with first identical match:
function* match(items, identity, match, remaining) {
  for (let item of items) {
    //:=> negative dipole hashed key compliment (all passengers)
    let candidate = retrieve(remaining, match(item));
     //:=> on matching iteration retirve matching dipole
    //:=> on yield couple iterated value with last array value 
    // from matching hash  
    if (candidate) yield [item, candidate];
    //:=> round-robin retrieve with insert
    else insert(remaining, identity(item), item);
  }
}

// Example:
let items = [{
  type: 'driver',
  direction: 'east',
  time: '9:15',
  name: ['Archibald Trump']
}, {
  type: 'passenger',
  direction: 'east',
  time: '9:15',
  name: ['Bacon Eater']
}, {
  type: 'passenger',
  direction: 'east',
  time: '9:15',
  name: ['Banjo Barney']
}, {
  type: 'passenger',
  direction: 'east',
  time: '9:15',
  name: ['Flimsy Stick']
}, {
  type: 'passenger',
  direction: 'west',
  time: '9:30',
  name: ['Big Red']
}, {
  type: 'passenger',
  direction: 'west',
  time: '9:35',
  name: ['Hathaway Anne']
}];

let remaining = new Map();
let pairs = match(
  items,
  item => '' + (item.type == 'driver') + item.direction + item.time,
  item => '' + (item.type == 'passenger') + item.direction + item.time,
  remaining
);

console.log('pairs',...pairs);
console.log('remaining',[...remaining.values()].reduceRight((a,b)=>a.concat(b)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: A note on optimality in terms of computational complexity: push and pop are indeed in O(1) on reasonable JS engines, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44031591/performance-of-array-push-vs-array-unshift - so multimap insertion and retrieval are also in O(1) amortized time.